# Trouble logging into gmail with Scrapy - "max redirections reached"

Tags: python, authentication, gmail, scrapy

I've been trying to get Scrapy to log in to my gmail account to no avail. Gmail seems to be re-directing a lot. After so many re-directs (I believe 20 is the default) it prints **"max redirections reached"** and the spider closes.

Any hints are appreciated, I've not used Scrapy to log in until now so I'm still a be of a newbie. It doesn't seem to be a very commonly asked question and I haven't had much luck searching SO amongst other websites.

**Spider Code**

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from gmailSpider.items import GmailspiderItem
from scrapy.http import FormRequest, Request

class LoginSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'gmail'
    start_urls = ['https://mail.google.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                    formdata={'login': 'email@gmail.com', 'password': 'password'},
                    callback='after_login')]

    def after_login(self, response):
        # check login succeed before going on
        if "The email or password you entered is incorrect." in response.body:
            self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
            return
        else:
            sel = Selector(response)
            print "success!"
            print sel.xpath('//title').extract()[0]
    # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

**Settings**

```
BOT_NAME = 'gmailSpider'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['gmailSpider.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'gmailSpider.spiders'
```

Thanks for reading,

Toby